# Cross-platform text, image, video Chat for Android, iOS and Web using Firebase/Parse/PubNub

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, firebase, pubnub

I want to develop a **cross platform** chat application which I can use to send **text,url,image,location,video** to my friends which can be on android/ios/web.

I want chat to be **realtime**, and want to make sure that even if user is not using application, he get a '**Notification**' for new incoming chat message.

How to do it using just Firebase or just Parse or just PubNub? If it is not possible, we can explore possibility of using them in combination.

Notes / Problems: 
1. Firebase: it has 'Firechat' for web, 'firechat/swiftchat' for iOS and 'chat' for android. how to synchronize them with each other?

2. PubNub has limitation of sending just 32kb in one message.
3. I read few places that Parse does not support realtime chat?

I tried searching for different questions here already, but did not find any solution that will satisfy all my requirements.

Comment: so you are asking people to do a job for you for free?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco
No, I am NOT asking do a job for me ! Nor I am asking for readymade code or anything.. I am asking for help. Isn't it the purpose of stackoverflow ? I have mentioned the issues I am facing in each platform..and I am looking for help.. I am new to android/ios programing and to stackoverflow community.. so I apologize if asking question like this if it hurt someone's feelings ! Suggest edits, they are most welcome if you feel its not the way to ask question but please don't unnecessarily downvote questions.. Thanks!

Comment: @Nis How did it go with pubnub and parse? I'm trying to the exact same project right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PubNub for realtime chat. There are SDKs for all platforms you listed.
For images, you send/receive the data with a image url, while storing the images using Parse.

As long as you use the same credentials (your pub/sub keys) to publish all messages to the same channel, all messages are synced no matter what platform your users are on.

For push notifications, you should be able to use either PubNub or Parse.

If you need to map user locations in realtime, try EON by PubNub too.
http://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help. I will try with PubNub and Parse.